# How to separate a file per day into hours in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I take a file with approximately 30000 lines per day. I take this every hour till end of the day and I want to separate this into hours. For example like below:

```
Hours    file  
00-01     23  
01-02     230  
02-03     3453
```

With awk command I count a file and is approximately 30000 lines per day.  Example of a file is like this.

```
200 | 2003| mandi | 2017-12-27 09:20:21 | end
```

There are 30000 lines into a file every day in a different hours.This is a reason why i want to separate into hours.

Please help me to separate this into hours, with "for" cycle or "while do".

Comment: Please add example of input file's content, the command you are using, the output you got, the one you wants.

Comment: this is my script but this take only per day not per hours.cat *file201712127* | grep -i name | wc -l

Comment: Please do not put code or data in comments - it is very hard to read. Instead, click `edit` under your original question and make sure everything is self-contained and up to-date in there. Thank you.

Comment: So all lines with a time `09:xx` should end up in a file called `09.csv`?

Comment: no.in text file and i want only a file that count how files are generated in this hour, like above format.

Answer (score 1):

Still not certain what you actually want, but I think this is close. Your sample file is not much use so I extended it as follows:

```
200 | 2003| mandi | 2017-12-27 09:20:21 | end 
190 | 2007| mandi | 2017-12-27 10:20:21 | end 
190 | 2007| mandi | 2017-12-27 10:30:21 | end 
190 | 2007| mandi | 2017-12-27 10:31:21 | end 
190 | 2007| mandi | 2017-12-27 10:31:25 | end 
190 | 2007| mandi | 2017-12-27 23:31:25 | end
```

Then, I use `GNU awk` as follows:

```
awk -F'|' '{split($4,a,/[ :]/);hour=a[3]+0; lines[hour]++}
    END{ for(h=0;h<24;h++)printf("%d-%d: %d\n",h,h+1,lines[h]) }' YourFile.csv
```

**Sample Output**

```
0-1: 0
1-2: 0
2-3: 0
3-4: 0
4-5: 0
5-6: 0
6-7: 0
7-8: 0
8-9: 0
9-10: 1
10-11: 4
11-12: 0
12-13: 0
13-14: 0
14-15: 0
15-16: 0
16-17: 0
17-18: 0
18-19: 0
19-20: 0
20-21: 0
21-22: 0
22-23: 0
23-24: 1
```

Comment: Hi but my file is not in csv. Is a terminal file exactly like this .

Comment: I don't understand - there is no such thing as a *"terminal file"*. If you want to treat it as a text file, just change the extension to `txt`. If you want commas separating the fields, change the colon in the script to a comma. If you want something else, please clock `edit` under your original question and change your question so it **properly shows** both your input data and output data.